# Nodejs V8 GC being inform before crash in Excel generation file

Tags: node.js, excel, crash, v8, heap-memory

I am using xlsx-chart node module in my application. This module use memory to generate excel charts from your data points. Sometimes when I have too many data points my node js app crash like this :

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[6420:000000CD560122F0]    77691 ms: Mark-sweep 2047.4 (2086.4) -> 2047.4 (2086.4) MB, 1235.2 / 0.1 ms  allocation failure GC in old space
requested
[6420:000000CD560122F0]    79246 ms: Mark-sweep 2047.4 (2086.4) -> 2047.4 (2086.4) MB, 1141.2 / 0.0 ms  last resort
[6420:000000CD560122F0]    80808 ms: Mark-sweep 2047.4 (2086.4) -> 2047.4 (2086.4) MB, 1561.1 / 0.0 ms  last resort


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000001D77B79BBE9 <JS Object>
    2: /* anonymous */ [C:\XXXX\base64.js:~7] [pc=000001A01E7EC475](this=000000BA
08CE36B1 <an Object with map 0000038E23FBE9A9>,input=0000017D18202201 <Very long string[50266376]>,utf8=000001D77B782241 <undefined>)
    3: arguments adaptor frame: 1->2
    4: generate [C:\XXXXX
```

At first I was trying to put the place that I call making excel file function inside try and catch blocks that if such heap error happens I just send a correct message to the user and restart my server. But it looks GC happens independent of try catch error.

So my main question is that how can I send the response to the user before CG crash and how can I restart the server automatically if such crash happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use of `--max-old-space-size` that will increase the maximum memory your `node.js` process can use.

And you can use the [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) tool to restart your application in case of crash.

---

**BUT**

I recommand you to find out what is the limit when you are generating your file. And either, up the maximum size your node.js can takes accordingly to the file you want to generate; or restreint the excel generation. Your node.js should never get this error, it should be anticipated.

Comment: Thanks. As I am using xlsx-chart moduole I could not really know how can I predict it;however, I have access to my data size but I do not know how can I convert it to the real size of the data that want to be written in an excel file. one other thing is that --max_old_space_size is a good option but still when it reach to the maximum --max_old_space_size  it will crash. I just want to terminate that process before any crash and send the user an answer that the excel file is too big to be generated.

Comment: The only thing I can see is to benchmark it. Look at how much your node.js process is using without processing the excel. Then call the excel creation and look at how much it takes now. Then try with multiple different generations and you will get an idea about what you want to calcul and what result in term of memory.

Comment: @Sam the module process have a method called [memoryUsage](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage) you could use it and if you see  that you are close to death (max memory) stop the excel generation and throw an error. But it's highly unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks  Grégory. I tried to increase my data points and then test to see up to when it will crash so made that data point as the limit but anyhow it is not a very robust way to prevent such problem.